# Why must Jewish kingship be hereditary?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, malchut-royalty

As we see in the scriptures many kings from the line of David sinned and caused devastation in Israel.

What is the logical reason for kingship being inherited no matter what kind of person is the king?

Why can't a prophet, or the Sanhedrin discharge a ruling king and appoint a better one?

Comment: "and appoint a better one" - You mean someone from the Davidic lineage?

Comment: By keeping them in the Davidic line, nobody can claim to be both a king and a priest. But generally, this adds to the nation's stability. Just read the Book of Kings and compare the North Kingdom of Israel to the South Kingdom of Judah. North keeps having someone who is sure he deserves the throne more overthrowing the next guy ... some barely last a year. In the South, the next king may be rotten, but everyone knows who the next king will be, and the one after that will hopefully be better. (Malbim actually raises the possibility of having the king swear to limit his powers, but...)

Comment: @pcoz for example. Let's stick to the existing tradition.

Comment: @AlBerko It would seem then that the choosing of Dovid and his descendants in correct order is super rational and is *begeder be'hani kavshi de'rachmana lamah lach* - there is no way you will ever be able to understand why this will turn out right, but it will.

Comment: @Shalom where is that Malbim?

Comment: @Harel13 it's Malbim's reading on the senior advisors' advice to new king Rechavam; "if you tell the people you love them and will serve them, they won't demand that you swear to conditions and limits on your power." (I Kings 12:7)

Comment: @Shalom thanks.